# question about Morse theory in Hilbert space

Tags: analysis, algebraic-topology, definition, morse-theory

This is sade to be the Morse theory in Hilbert space ,and i want to know the definition (or where i can find it ) of :

- The qth singular relative homology groupe
- The qth critical group

[image]
[image]

Please;

Answer (score 1):

A definition of relative homology is given for instance on page 115 of Hatcher's book on algebraic topology, which is freely available on [his website](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html).

The $q$-th critical group seems to be defined in your text itself as $H_q(\Phi^c\cap U,\Phi^c\cap U\backslash\{u\}:\mathbb{F})$.